# Concurrent Programming - Python Processes - Race Condition - Is Example causes race condition or not?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, race-condition

Hey Brilliant StackOverflow Community,

I am aware that the race condition can occur when the shared output of a set of operations depended on which process finishes first. I am wondering if the global variable, a list, will be impacted by the race condition.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def non_race_condition(value):
    return value + 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
holder = [] # will this be impacted? 
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    for x in pool.map(non_race_condition,[10 for _ in range(10)]):
        holder.append(x)
print(holder)
```

My instinct tells me that the race condition should not impact the holder since processes don't have a shared memory to read and write. Is my instinct correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: You should fix your indentation errors. But to answer your question: the `map` method is guaranteed to return results in *job submission order*, so there is no race condition issue. But this is a horrible example since even if there were no order guarantee, how could you end up with `holder` being anything other than `[20] * 10`?

Comment: If you were to change your example to `for x in pool.map(non_race_condition, range(10)):`, then `holder` will always be `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`. If instead you started multiple processes to which you passed a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance that the processes wrote the result to, then you would have a race condition and the order in which the results were written to the queue would be indeterminate unless you wrote additional code to order it in job-submission order.

Comment: @Booboo Hey Booboo thank you so much for your clarification. I fixed my indentation error. Are you suggesting functions running in Process Pool do not have a shared memory; therefore, the holder will always be the same output? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am saying that `map` by definition fixes the output in a very specific order, just like the standard non-multiprocessing, built-in `map` function. It has nothing to do whether shared memory is involved or not. That is to say: Each element of the results returned corresponds one-for-one to each element of the passed *iterable* being passed to the `map` function.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you so much for your patience! I get it now! I hope you have a great day ahead!

Comment: Hey @Booboo, Would you kindly put your comment as an answer? So that I can upvote  & accept it to close this question. Thank you so much and I hope you have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: the `map` method is guaranteed to return results in job submission order, so there is no race condition issue. But even if there were no order guarantee, how could you end up with `holder` being anything other than `[20] * 10` given your example?

But if you were to change your example to `for x in pool.map(non_race_condition, range(10)):`, then `holder` will always be `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]` because `map` by definition fixes the output in a very specific order, just like the standard non-multiprocessing, built-in `map` function. If, however, you instead started multiple processes to which you passed a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance that the processes wrote the result to, then you would have a race condition and the order in which the results were written to the queue would be indeterminate unless you wrote additional code to ensure somehow that results were written in a specific order. This is because there is no guarantee that just because a process is the first one to start that it will automatically be the first one to write its result to the queue; there are just too many factors that govern that.